# Recursion : why it is giving me the error SIGABRT

Tags: c++, recursion, fibonacci

Hii I am recieving the error of `SIGMABRT` can anyone help with this ??

```
// { Driver Code Starts
//Initial Template for C++

#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;



//User function Template for C++

class Solution {

   int *arr ;

  public:

    int firstElement(int n) 

    {

         arr =new int[n];

         for( int i =0; i<=n;i++)

         {

             arr[i]=-1;

         }

         arr[0]=0;

         arr[1]=1;

         int k = recursion_fibo_series(n , arr); 

         delete []arr;

         return k;

    }

    int recursion_fibo_series(int n ,int arr[])

         {

             if(arr[n]!=-1){

                 return arr[n];

             }

             else

             {

                 arr[n]= recursion_fibo_series(n-1,arr)+recursion_fibo_series(n-2,arr);

                 return arr[n];

             }

         }

};



// { Driver Code Starts.

int main() {

    int t;

    cin >> t;


    while (t--) {


        int  n;

        cin >> n ;

        Solution ob;

        cout<<ob.firstElement(n)<<endl;

    }

    return 0;

}

  // } Driver Code Ends
```

Answer (score 4):

You do

```
arr =new int[n];
```

and to initialize the array you do

```
for( int i =0; i<=n;i++)
```

That loop will go *out of bounds* of the array. Since array undexes are zero-based, an array of `n` elements will have valid indexes from `0` to `n - 1`. Your loop uses `n` as an index.

Using out of bounds indexes leads to *undefined behavior*.

Change loop condition to *less than* rather than less than or equal:

```
for( int i = 0; i < n; i++)
```

---

Also, the first thing you do in the `recursion_fibo_series` function is:

```
if(arr[n]!=-1)
```

where you again use index `n` as the index, which is out of bounds.

And you continue to do that inside this function.

Answer (score 2):

This is an out of bounds array access

```
 arr = new int[n];
 for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
 {
     arr[i]=-1;
 }
```

You want `arr = new int[n + 1];`.

Comment: Thanks i jut forget that .thanks a lot